# I'm trying to draw a SRTM3-Tile with Multithreading in Java - what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics2d

I'm trying to paint a Srtm3-Tile with the Help of Multithreading. If i use only a single Thread every works fine, but when i use Multithreading the graphic ends up in a mess. Currently i use 12 Cores - any idea?

Here is the code:

Thread-Init this piece of code resides in the paint method:

```
            int cpuCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); //12 Cores
            int blockSize = size / cpuCount;
            BigMapPOJO bigMapPOJO = new BigMapPOJO(srtmBorderPOJO.getFileName(), bigMap);


            SrtmV2Thread threadArray[] = new SrtmV2Thread[cpuCount];
            //Init Threads, cpuCount=1 works fine...
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
                SrtmV2Thread srtmV2Thread;
                if (i == cpuCount - 1) {
                    srtmV2Thread = new SrtmV2Thread(g, map, bigMapPOJO, 0 + (i * blockSize), size, srtmBorderPOJO, min, max);
                } else {
                    srtmV2Thread = new SrtmV2Thread(g, map, bigMapPOJO, 0 + (i * blockSize), blockSize + (i * blockSize), srtmBorderPOJO, min, max);
                }
                threadArray[i] = srtmV2Thread;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
                //Start Threads
                threadArray[i].start();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++) {
                try {
                    //Wait for completion
                    threadArray[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Run Method of the Thread:

```
          @Override
         public void run() {

    GeoPosition geoPosition0 = new GeoPosition(srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord0().getLat(), srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord0().getLon());
    GeoPosition geoPosition1 = new GeoPosition(srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord1().getLat(), srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord1().getLon());
    GeoPosition geoPosition2 = new GeoPosition(srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord2().getLat(), srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord2().getLon());
    GeoPosition geoPosition3 = new GeoPosition(srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord3().getLat(), srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord3().getLon());

    Point2D pt0 = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(geoPosition0, map.getZoom());
    Point2D pt1 = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(geoPosition1, map.getZoom());
    Point2D pt2 = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(geoPosition2, map.getZoom());
    Point2D pt3 = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(geoPosition3, map.getZoom());

    /*
    0-1
    3-2
     */
    //calulate width and height of a single tile
    int resHor = (int) ((pt1.getX() - pt0.getX()));
    int resVer = (int) ((pt3.getY() - pt0.getY()));

    int horStep = (int) (size / (double) resHor);
    int verStep = (int) (size / (double) resVer);
    
    //start and end comes from the thread init
    for (int y = start; y < end; y += verStep) {

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += horStep) {

            double ver = y / (double) (size);
            double hor = x / (double) (size);

            GeoPosition geoPosition = new GeoPosition(srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord0().getLat() - ver, srtmV2BorderPOJO.getCoord0().getLon() + hor);
            Point2D ptHeight = map.getTileFactory().geoToPixel(geoPosition, map.getZoom());

            short height = bigMapPOJO.getBigMap()[y][x];
            if (height < 0) {
                height = 0;
            }

            double percent = getPercentFromHeight(min, max, height);
            Color colorHeight = genColor(percent);

            double red = colorHeight.getRed();
            double green = colorHeight.getGreen();
            double blue = colorHeight.getBlue();
            
            //draw point in calculated color, according to height
            java.awt.Color color = new java.awt.Color((int) (red * 255), (int) (green * 255), (int) (blue * 255), 255);
            g.setColor(color);

            Point point = new Point((int) ptHeight.getX(), (int) ptHeight.getY());

            g.draw(new Rectangle(point));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two reasons:

1. `Graphics2D` is an abstract class which is not guaranteed to be thread safe. So executing whatever on it is a mistake in general. It could work in some cases, but doesn't have to.
2. Your code is not thread-tolerant itself: `g.setColor(color);` is not atomic/synchronized with a `g.draw(new Rectangle(point));` call. So it would overlap between threads and be executed in an unpredictable order across them like this:

> thread 1: setColor(color1);
>
> thread 2: setColor(color2);
>
> thread 1: draw() // with color2;
>
> thread 2: draw() // with color2 also;

So consider:

1. Synchronize `setColor` with `draw` for example in a basic way:

   ```
        Point point = new Point((int) ptHeight.getX(), (int) ptHeight.getY());
        synchronized(lockObject) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.draw(new Rectangle(point));
        }
   ```

where the `lockObject` is an object shared between threads

2. (Recommended) Avoid using `Graphics2D` with multiple threads. Consider doing only your math and other preparations in multiple thread and call `Graphics2D` from a single one.

Comment: As you suggest, now I'm using a matrix[size][size] in my Threads and draw the matrix in the paint method. - Works like a charm.